# kubectl top is trying to connect to heapster instead of metrcis server

Tags: centos, kubernetes

According to readme in [heapster repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster), the project is now deprecated. The current recommended solution is to use [the metrics server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/core-metrics-pipeline/) which acorrding to documentation can be accessed by using `kubectl top`. I have deployed it on my bare-metal CentOs machine. Unfortunately it seems it does not work out of the box:

```
bash-4.2$ kubectl get pod metrics-server-bb9ffc6b8-7c25g -n=kube-system
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
metrics-server-bb9ffc6b8-7c25g   1/1       Running   0          9h
bash-4.2$ kubectl top pods
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource (get services http:heapster:)
bash-4.2$
```

It seems like it still tries to access heapster and it is not compatible with metrics server. Do I need to perform additional setup to make it work?

I'm using kubectl and kubelet v1.9.3.

EDIT: After I've deployed heapster, I can see usage charts on dashboard. So it seems like eve if it is officially deprecated, it works as expected.

Comment: if you used kubeadm to install your cluster, maybe the problem is cadvisor is disabled https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/633

Comment: heapster doesn't need the cadvisor to work?

Comment: The Heapster pod discovers all nodes in the cluster and queries usage information from each node's Kubelet the on-machine Kubernetes agent. The Kubelet itself fetches the data from cAdvisor, I think cAdvisor is integrated in kubernetes in the newers version, but disabled by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl top` uses Metrics-Server instead of Heapster as a source for metrics starting from v1.10, but in v1.9.3, Heapster is still required.

Here is the merged [pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/56206) about it with Milestone = v1.10.